# Debian: How to create SOCKS proxy server to exit on specific network interface?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, proxy, socks

I have a setup with two internet connections.

- eth0 - Internet connection 1
- eth1 - Internet connection 2

**How can I create a SOCKS 4/5 server that will take connections coming from eth0 and proxy the traffic through eth1 ?**

I saw that you can use ssh to create a simple SOCKS proxy, but I am unable to proxy the traffic through eth1.

I also tried Dante, but with no success.

Comment: Did you manage to setup Dante successfully?

Comment: IMHO only use on the second device a gateway and it will automatically route the internet traffic

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can not make any service use specific interface for oubound traffic. The only way to rule outbound traffic is to use `route` utility. This is system wide setting.

Comment: It surely can be done, but I don't know how. Dante can do it, but I am incapable of configuring it ..

Comment: wget --bind-address and curl --interface does that too.

Comment: @themihai how should wget and curl work like an proxy? it was asked whoch proxy or how the proxy thst is unknowncan use one inbound and one outbound interface